# Executar comandos DOS no Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

Preciso saber qual comando no *Visual Studio 2013* executa o comando de parar um serviço de sistema Windows. No `DOS` eu faço assim:

```
net stop Audiosrv
netstart Audiosrv
exit
```

A Outra pergunta é como executar os comandos `DOS` dentro do Visual Studio 2013 - Visual Basic. Chamando ou não o SHELL `cmd.exe`

Tentei fazer assim porém não está dando certo, pois ele não está chamando os comandos `DOS`.

```
Private Sub ExecutarComando()

 Dim comando As String = "/del C:\1.txt"

Shell ("cmd.exe /c " & comando)

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido ,
Resolvi assim :

Para iniciar

```
Shell("net start WSearch") 'Windows Search Start'
```

Para Parar

```
Shell("net stop Wsearch")'Windows Search Stop'
```

Comment: Mauricio, se esta é a resposta que funcionou, marque-a como correta clicando no ícone à esquerda, embaixo da pontuação da resposta.

Comment: Eu não consigo meu amigo, não tenho pontuação ainda ;

Comment: Me ajuda ai ; marca como resposta por favor faz essa gentileza pra mim; Ótimo dia pra você . @bfavaretto

Comment: Deveria conseguir sim. A pergunta é sua, só você pode marcar a resposta. Nem eu que sou moderador posso fazer isso pelos outros.

Comment: @bfavaretto porque meu tópico está negativado ?
Não fiz nada errado .

Comment: Não sei o que levou alguém a votar contra, podem ter achado confuso, que faltou pesquisa... Não tenho como saber. Sobre aceitar a resposta, veja instruções aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta. Se não funcionar, me avise que mensagem o sistema deu.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não sei o que fazer , só queria ajudar a comunidade e marcar como feito ; Porque deu certo aqui e resolvi um problema que estava me dando dor de cabeça . não queria que outros usuários passassem pelo que passei .

Comment: Agradeço você querer ajudar, esse é o espírito. É sempre bom registrar a resposta que funcionou. Não ligue para o -1 lá em cima, faz parte, todo mundo leva esses votos uma vez ou outra.

Comment: @bfavaretto pois é ; Já estou com 32 anos . Estou na metade da vida , sou um pacifista.

Answer (score 3):

O comando DOS `NET` é um executável - *net.exe*. Assim sendo, ele pode ser invocado como um executável via classe *Process*. Aqui vai um wrapper que retorna uma string contendo o resultado do comando. Exemplo de uso:

```
retorno = ExecutaComando("net.exe", "start Audiosrv")
```

Aqui vai a função em VisualBasic.NET:

```
Private Shared Function ExecutaComando(pComando As String, pParametros As String) As String
    Dim _ret As String = ""

    Dim procShell As New Process()

    'Seu comando vai aqui.
    procShell.StartInfo.FileName = pComando

    'Os argumentos, aqui.
    procShell.StartInfo.Arguments = pParametros

    procShell.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    procShell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    procShell.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    procShell.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    procShell.Start()

    Dim streamReader As New StreamReader(procShell.StandardOutput.BaseStream, procShell.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding)

    Do
        Dim _line As String = streamReader.ReadLine()
        If (IsNothing(_line)) Then Exit Do
        _ret = _ret + _line + vbCrLf
    Loop

    streamReader.Close()

    Return _ret

End Function
```

Por exemplo, o seguinte uso:

```
ExecutaComando("net.exe", "stop w3svc")
```

Retorna o seguinte valor em uma máquina Windows 8.1 com IIS instalado:

```
The World Wide Web Publishing Service service is stopping.
The World Wide Web Publishing Service service was stopped successfully.
```

Você pode utilizar o mesmo método com CMD. Exemplo:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c del C:\1.txt")
```

Comment: To olhando aqui acho que você não entendeu .
Net start é um comando DOS , AudioSRV é o serviço de audio como exemplo coloquei .

Comment: @MauricioPerroni Eu entendi, sim. Vários comandos DOS são, na verdade, executáveis como no caso do NET. Sinta-se à vontade para testar o código acima.

Comment: Jóia vou testar agora .

Comment: Deu erro , olhe o erro que deu ....

Comment: Link do erro .
http://imgur.com/AEJPmtc

Comment: É uma função, não uma classe completa; você precisa inserir esta função em uma classe/módulo.

Comment: Ué mais foi exatamente o que você me mandou ... .

Comment: Tentei colocar em uma classe módulo ele está me retornando um erro ; Vou postar para você e para o Administrador.

link do erro de classe/modulo : http://imgur.com/C9nxphT

@OnoSendai

Comment: Tipo eu resolvi com o SHELL

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Shell("net stop TeamViewer9")
    End Sub

O problema que o CMD não está sendo executado por um admin então o comando não está sendo executado .

Comment: Pronto , quando roda a solução no meu VB é simples só rodar com o botão direito , permissões de administrador e vai tranquilo .